# Converting a lowercase char in a char array to an uppercase char (java)

Tags: java, arrays, char, uppercase

Hello I am trying to write a little segment of code that checks if each `char` in a `char` array is lower case or uppercase.  Right now it uses the char's ASCII number to check.  After it checks it should convert the char to upper case if it is not already so:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < charmessage.length; counter++) {
    if (91 - charmessage[counter] <= 0 && 160 - charmessage[counter] != 0) {
    charmessage[counter] = charmessage[counter].toUpperCase();
    } 
}
```

`charmessage` is already initialized previously in the program.  The 160 part is to make sure it doesn't convert a space to uppercase.  How do I get the `.toUpperCase` method to work?

Comment: And one more thing, from the `Character` Documentation: "In general, `String.toUpperCase()` should be used to map characters to uppercase. String case mapping methods have several benefits over Character case mapping methods. String case mapping methods can perform locale-sensitive mappings, context-sensitive mappings, and 1:M character mappings, whereas the Character case mapping methods cannot." Just something to keep in mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way. First check if the character is a letter and if it is lowercase. After this just use the Character.toUpperCase(char ch)

```
if(Character.isLetter(charmessage[counter]) && Character.isLowerCase(charmessage[counter])){
    charmessage[counter] = Character.toUpperCase(charmessage[counter]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I only did it using the ASCII because I didn't know that isLetter existed.

Comment: The `isLetter()` test is either redundant or too restrictive. See the Javadoc for `isLowerCase()`. As a matter of fact so is the entire test: see the Javadoc for `toUpperCase()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Character#toUpperCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29) for that. Example:

```
char a = 'a';
char upperCase = Character.toUpperCase(a);
```

It has some limitations, though. It's very important you know that the world is aware of many more characters that can fit within the 16-bit range.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "stackoverflow";
    int stringLenght = s.length();
    char arr[] = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = stringLenght - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char a = (arr[i]);
        char upperCase = Character.toUpperCase(a);
        System.out.print(upperCase);
       }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).