# How to turn a char to upper case in java without using String

Tags: java, char, uppercase, lowercase

Is there an **easier way** to do this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char x = 'a';     //If 'a' I want 'A', if 'z' i want 'Z', and so on.
    String aux = "";
    aux=""+x;
    aux=aux.toUpperCase();

    x=aux.charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a lowercase char in a char array to an uppercase char (java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635264/converting-a-lowercase-char-in-a-char-array-to-an-uppercase-char-java)

Comment: if it's only ascii A-Z, write your own method:)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`Character.toUpperCase(char ch)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase(char)).